# How to set variable from a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to set a variable from a SQL query:

```
declare @ModelID uniqueidentifer

Select @ModelID = select modelid from models
where areaid = 'South Coast'
```

Obviously I'm not doing this right as it doesn't work. Can somebody suggest a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: [SET vs. SELECT When Assigning Variables](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/set-vs-select-assigning-variables.aspx)

Comment: It's uniqueidentifier. Not uniqueidentifer.

Comment: And uniqueidentifer is copy and pasted about 4 times.

Answer (score 684):

### Using `SELECT`

```
SELECT @ModelID = m.modelid 
  FROM MODELS m
 WHERE m.areaid = 'South Coast'
```

### Using `SET`

```
SET @ModelID = (SELECT m.modelid 
                  FROM MODELS m
                 WHERE m.areaid = 'South Coast');
```

### Then you can use `SELECT` to show the value of `@ModelID` or use the variable into your code.

```
SELECT @ModelID
```

[See this question for the difference between using SELECT and SET in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/tsql-set-vs-select-when-assigning-variables).

### Warning

If this `SELECT` statement returns *multiple values* (bad to begin with):

- When using `SELECT`, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned (as womp said), without any error or warning (this may cause logic bugs)
- The `SET` query returns error only if you DON'T put the semicolon in the end of query

Comment: If this select statement returns multiple values: in the first case, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned (as womp said), without any error or warning (this may cause logic bugs); in the second case, an error will occur.

Comment: BTW, the case using SET needs a pair of brackets: SET @ModelID = (SELECT ...)

Comment: I would use TOP 1 with select, to have only 1 result, e.g. SET @ModelID = (SELECT TOP 1 m.modelid 
                  FROM MODELS m
                 WHERE m.areaid = 'South Coast')

Comment: In case using set when multiple values are returned then how to handle it using exception handling?

Comment: Sometimes you want an error if there's an unexpected duplicate result rather than quietly using an unexpected result.

Comment: Now if SELECT statement returns mutliple value, we will get error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: While it's extremally useful it doesn't seem to work with if exists(select @a = a... constructs which is really sad as it forces you to do the same thing twice once to check and another time to fetch the vars without using if exists(). Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 53):

```
SELECT @ModelID = modelid
FROM Models
WHERE areaid = 'South Coast'
```

If your select statement returns multiple values, your variable is assigned the last value that is returned.

For reference on using SELECT with variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259186%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 42):

```
declare @ModelID uniqueidentifer

--make sure to use brackets
set @ModelID = (select modelid from models
where areaid = 'South Coast')

select @ModelID
```

Comment: This question all ready has an answer it didn't need answering again, I can't even see what's different between yours and Ponies answer?

Comment: @JoshuaDuxbury it provides a working copy paste version

Answer (score 29):

I prefer just setting it from the declare statement

```
DECLARE @ModelID uniqueidentifer = (SELECT modelid 
                                    FROM models
                                    WHERE areaid = 'South Coast')
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `TOP 1` if the query returns multiple rows.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @ModelID = m.modelid 
  FROM MODELS m
 WHERE m.areaid = 'South Coast'
```

Comment: It won't actually cause an error in SQL it will select the last record (although it could cause a resulting error in an application if you are using this value and it is incorrect)

Answer (score 14):

There are three approaches:

1. [DECLARE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [SET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) -- Microsoft Recommended approach
3. [SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Below query details the advantage and disadvantage of each:

```sql
-- First way, 
DECLARE @test int = (SELECT 1)
       , @test2 int = (SELECT a from (values (1),(2)) t(a)) -- throws error

-- advantage: declare and set in the same place
-- Disadvantage: can be used only during declaration. cannot be used later

-- Second way
DECLARE @test int  
       , @test2 int 

SET @test = (select 1)
SET @test2 = (SELECT a from (values (1),(2)) t(a)) -- throws error

-- Advantage: ANSI standard. 
-- Disadvantage: cannot set more than one variable at a time

-- Third way
DECLARE @test int, @test2 int 
SELECT @test = (select 1)
      ,@test2 = (SELECT a from (values (1),(2)) t(a)) -- throws error

-- Advantage: Can set more than one variable at a time
-- Disadvantage: Not ANSI standard
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this, but remember that your query gives 1 result, multiple results will throw the exception.

```
declare @ModelID uniqueidentifer
Set @ModelID = (select Top(1) modelid from models where areaid = 'South Coast')
```

Another way:

```
Select Top(1)@ModelID = modelid from models where areaid = 'South Coast'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Select @ModelID =m.modelid 
From   MODELS m
Where  m.areaid = 'South Coast'
```

In this case if you have two or more results returned then your result is the last record. So be aware of this if you might have two more records returned as you might not see the expected result.

Answer (score 6):

## To ASSIGN variables using a SQL select the best practice is as shown below

```
->DECLARE co_id INT ;
->DECLARE sname VARCHAR(10) ;

->SELECT course_id INTO co_id FROM course_details ;
->SELECT student_name INTO sname FROM course_details;
```

#### IF you have to assign more than one variable in a single line you can use this same SELECT INTO

```
->DECLARE val1 int;
->DECLARE val2 int;

->SELECT student__id,student_name INTO val1,val2 FROM student_details;

--HAPPY CODING--
```

Comment: "best practice" -- source?

Comment: IF u have more than one columns to select from a Table then u can easily assign it using a single SELECT INTO statement instead of repeating the code !!

Answer (score 0):

My use case was that I wanted to set a variable to a string.  All the other answers here show how to set a variable using the output of a SELECT statement.  Here's how to do it with a simple string:

```
DECLARE @ModelID varchar(60) = 'Model T'
```