# SQL: Why can't I set a variable to the result of a query?

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

I'm trying to run this query on the SO Data Explorer:

```
DECLARE @totalRep float

SET @totalRep = SELECT SUM(Users.Reputation) FROM Users
```

And I keep getting

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reputation will be an integer :-).

Comment: Reputation CAN be an integer, but sometime you need it as a float :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set variable from a SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974683/how-to-set-variable-from-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT @totalRep = SUM(Users.Reputation) FROM Users
```