# Having a basic SQL issue using microsoft sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I am new to SQL statements and I am guessing this is something obvious so I apologize ahead of time for the newbie question.

Here is the code:

```
use test;
declare @time_24_2 int;
declare @hours_diff_2 int;

SELECT 
    end_date_full 
FROM 
    example 
WHERE 
    datediff(hour, getdate(), end_date_full) < 24
GROUP BY 
    end_date_full

SET @time_24_2 = end_date_full;
select @time_24_2
```

This is my code and I am simply trying to pull the `end_date_full` column of every row that fits the criteria. However every time I try to use the column `end_date_full` like seen below I get an error that says *Unknown column name*.

Any help would be amazing!

P.S `end_date_full` is a column name and it works for the first select statement, just not the `SET` statement.

Comment: Duplicate?: [How to set variable from a SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3974683/456814).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are trying to use the column name outside a query when you assign it to variable. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT @time_24_2 = end_date_full 
FROM example 
WHERE datediff(hour, getdate(), end_date_full) < 24
group by end_date_full
```