# Output Parameter incorrect syntax near SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im working on stored procedure in `SQL SERVER`. From this query im getting list of `Tests` with pagination (skip and size). I want to get total count of `Tests` in `Tests` table. I want to do it by `OUTPUT` parameter. My query looks like this:

```
@size INT,
@skip INT,
@orderDir VARCHAR(4),
@orderBy VARCHAR(20),
@totalCount INT OUTPUT

AS 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Ids (
        TestId INT
    );

    INSERT INTO #Ids SELECT TestId FROM Tests;

    SELECT SomeStuff
    FROM Tests t JOIN TestLines tl ON t.TestId = tl.TestId 
    GROUP BY SomeStuff
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @orderDir = 'asc'AND @orderBy = 'TestId' THEN t.TestId END,
        CASE WHEN @orderDir = 'desc' AND @orderBy = 'TestId' THEN t.TestId END DESC,
        -- more case when here
    OFFSET @skip ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @size ROWS ONLY;

    SET @totalCount = SELECT COUNT(TestId) FROM #Ids

    DROP TABLE #Ids;

END
```

I cant create procedure with query above. On line `SET @totalCount = SELECT COUNT(TestId) FROM #Ids` i get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'

My qustion is, how to make it work properly? How to get that value as `OUTPUT` from stored procedure?

Comment: Try  SET @totalCount = (SELECT COUNT(TestId) FROM #Ids)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set variable from a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974683/how-to-set-variable-from-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SELECT` directly :

```
SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(TestId) 
FROM #Ids;
```

Or you can use `subquery` :

```
SET @totalCount  = (SELECT COUNT(TestId) FROM #Ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix by this way

- Using `SELECT`

```
    SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(TestId) FROM #Ids
```

- Using `SET`

```
   SET @totalCount = (SELECT COUNT(TestId) FROM #Ids)
```