# SQL SERVER : Stored Procedure WITH OUTPUT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to create a stored procedure in sql server in order to check username and password in authentication procedure. I have 3 parameters : `@username` to check, `@password` to check and `@authent` that return 1 if the user is authent and 0 if not.
Apparently I did wrong because when I run code, I have this error :

> Incorrect syntax to '@authent'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE authentUser 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @username varchar50, 
    @password varchar50,
    @authent bit OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PROFACE.dbo.Utilisateurs WHERE username = @username AND password = @password)
        @authent = 1;
END
RETURN
GO
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code and how can I correct it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a stred procedure and output, it is simply that a separate statement @authent = 1 is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly**, You need to use `Set` or `Select` to assign value

```
set @authent = 1; -- or select @authent = 1
```

**Secondly**, Make sure that you execute stored procedure like this way

```
DECLARE @result bit;

EXEC authentUser
    @username = '123',
    @password = '123',
    @authent = @result OUTPUT;

SELECT @result;
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding

[How to set variable from a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974683/how-to-set-variable-from-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE authentUser 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @username varchar50, 
        @password varchar50,
        @authent bit OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PROFACE.dbo.Utilisateurs WHERE username = @username AND password = @password)
           set @authent = 1;
    END
    RETURN
    GO
```

Comment: While this answer might resolve the problem, you should add an explanation to help the OP know the reason why.