# Apply case-when logic to different queries

Tags: sql-server, variables, select, case

Currently I am doing this:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
       WHEN [GAML 3] IN (SELECT [A_CUSTOMER] FROM [COM_TAB].[dbo].[A_C]) 
          THEN  'YES' 
          ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS [A_C] 
FROM
    table1
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    @[A_C_Case_Logic] 
FROM
    table1
```

This is due to I will apply same logic to different queries, for example:

```
SELECT *, @[A_C_Case_Logic] 
FROM Shipments

SELECT *, @[A_C_Case_Logic] 
FROM Backlog

SELECT *, @[A_C_Case_Logic] 
FROM Inventory
```

I create a connection to Excel Power BI to create charts from these queries.

I would appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set variable from a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974683/how-to-set-variable-from-a-sql-query)

Comment: So, declare a variable and set its value.  Then reference the variable in your `SELECT`

Comment: how to declare the varible to pull the text and add it to the sentence? that is my question :$

Comment: declare @[A_C_Case_Logic]  set = 'WHEN [GAML 3] IN (SELECT [A_CUSTOMER] FROM [COM_TAB].[dbo].[A_C]) THEN  'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS [A_C]'  ..... would it be something like this?

Comment: yes, something like that. except you need to declare the data type for the variable, and Select from the table where [GAM 3] exists. So, something like: `declare @MyVar varchar(3) = SELECT (CASE WHEN [GAML 3] IN (SELECT [A_CUSTOMER] FROM [A_C] THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) FROM table1;`

Comment: it worked like this after declaring the variable: 

  DECLARE A_CUSTOMER_VARIABLE AS VARCHAR(MAX) 

  SET A_CUSTOMER_VARIABLE = (SELECT [ A_CUSTOMER ] FROM [1_COMMON_TABLES].[dbo].AC) 

  DECLARE SQL  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
  SET SQL = 'SELECT *,'+@A_CUSTOMER_VARIABLE+'FROM SHIPMENTS'

  EXEC (SQL)