# I'm having trouble creating a stored procedure using the AdventureWorks database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Part 2: Create a stored procedure using the product and product inventory table. This stored procedure should declare a variable and set it the count of all products in the product table. If the count is greater than or equal to 20 the stored procedure should display a message that says "Inventory count is greater than or equal to 20". Otherwise, it should say "Inventory count for the products is less than 20".

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Moreorless20ProductInventory
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @countprod INT

    SELECT @countprod = countprod 
    FROM
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         INTO countprod
         FROM Production.ProductInventory);

    IF @countprod >= 20 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 20' as col1;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'The number of products is less than 20' as col1;
    END IF;
END
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Moreorless20ProductInventory, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Moreorless20ProductInventory, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Moreorless20ProductInventory, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near ';'

Comment: Why ar eyou trying to use an `INTO` in the same clause you are performing a variable assignment, and why is that `INTO` in a subquery?

Comment: Also, please have a read of the FAQ post [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Dumping the assignment and the your attempt into a question isn't really a question; it just expecting people to debug your code for you. Explain what you don't understand and what about the research you did you didn't either.

Answer (score 5):

`INTO` denotes *creating a new table*, not populating a variable. Try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Moreorless20ProductInventory
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @countprod int;

  SELECT @countprod = COUNT(*) FROM Production.ProductInventory;

  IF @countprod >= 20 
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 20' as col1;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'The number of products is less than 20' as col1;
  END
END
```

Also a much more efficient way to get the total number of rows in a table is to use the metadata:

```
SELECT @countprod = SUM([rows]) FROM sys.partitions
  WHERE index_id IN (0, 1)
  AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'Production.ProductInventory');
```

See [Bad habits: Counting rows the hard way](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value to variable multiple ways:

1. **ANSI WAY**

```sql
DECLARE @countprod INT

SET  @countprod = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM Production.ProductInventory);
```

2. **TSQL Way**

```sql
DECLARE @countprod INT

SELECT @countprod = COUNT(*) FROM Production.ProductInventory;
```

3. **T-SQL: Directly set value in DECLARE**

```sql
DECLARE @countprod INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Production.ProductInventory);
```

I have written in detail about this, in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62035659/634935