# SQL Store ID from selected Row to declared variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Cars` table and used this query to select a row with `MaxSpeed = 200` condition:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Cars
WHERE MaxSpeed = 200
ORDER BY [ID] DESC;
```

This query works very well, but now I need to store this row ID to a variable. I can declare an int variable, but I don't know how can get this row ID.

```
DECLARE @id AS INT;
```

Comment: `TOP 1 ORDER BY [ID] DESC` is equivalent to `SELECT MAX([ID]) FROM Cars . . .`

Comment: @Squirrel: **except** two points: **(1)** you need a `GROUP BY` when using `MAX(ID)` in your `SELECT`, and **(2)** if there are two or more entries with the same `MaxSpeed`, the `MAX(ID)` approach might return **multiple rows** (while `SELECT TOP (1)` will only return a single row). You cannot handle assignment to a variable when multiple rows are returned ....

Comment: Should be flagged as a duplicate of which there are many e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974683/how-to-set-variable-from-a-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply assign the value from the `SELECT` query to your variable:

```
DECLARE @id AS INT;

SELECT TOP 1 
    @id = ID
FROM Cars
WHERE MaxSpeed = 200
ORDER BY [ID] DESC;

SELECT @id;
```