# Difference Between Set @Variable= and Select @Variable =ColumnName from TableName

Tags: sql-server

Kindly eleborate me the difference Between Set and Select clause while Providing value to a Variable or Even  a  Column.

```
Declare @var nvarchar(Max)

Set @var= (Select TestName+ cAst(TestId as nvarchar) from TblTest where TestID=1)

Insert into TblTest(TestName)
Values (@var)

--------------------------------

Declare @var nvarchar(Max)

Select @var= (Select TestNAme + Cast(TestId as Nvarchar(MAx)) from TblTest Where TestID=1)

Insert into TblTest(TestName)
Values(@var)


-------------------------------
```

Values and result I am getting is Same in Both. 
But just wondering if there is any Difference. and if Any which Should I prefer. 
And Which one uses less Resources.

Comment: Try assigning to two variables in each of examples `@var` and `@var1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL - SET versus SELECT when assigning variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/t-sql-set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables)

Comment: Set variable is used for assigning the values to a variable
in your case the result of your query is store in var.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to my question, 
Initializing a variable with Select commands consumes lesser resources than using Set command. 
Other than this Usability is easy and compact.

I wont need to Write Set again and again.