# T-SQL and when searching for a non-exisitng row the variable is set to its previous/initial value instead of NULL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

This problem is of course me not understanding SQL 2008 on an expert level but I really don't understand this scenario.

If I have the below query - and ID 9 does **not** exist:

```
declare @tmpInt int = 5
select @tmpInt=coalesce(id,0) from MyView where id=9
print @tmpInt
```

Why is this printing `5` as set initially!? I would expect `0` - or maybe even `null`?

If I do the same query on an existing row, it will naturally set the ID of that row.

**UPDATE**

There has been two answers already but maybe I need to clarify - how can I get the `coalesce` value of `0` in to my variable, if no rows exists? Is it possible? Otherwise I would need to initialize the `@tmpInt` variable before each query (I am using `@tmpInt` in many queries).

Comment: Frankly, initializing @tmpint before each query is probably the best, most efficient method.  It's exactly what I would do.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/t-sql-set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables/3945448#3945448 for further details on using SET vs. SELECT for variable assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out, your `WHERE` clause is filtering all rows, so the variable is never changed.  If you need to work around this, you could use the `MAX()` aggregation - this will let your `COALESCE()` statement fire even when no rows are returned.

Example below:

```
DECLARE @tmpInt INT = 5
SELECT @tmpInt = COALESCE(MAX(id),0) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 1 AS id -- replace this with your table
  ) s 
WHERE id=9
PRINT @tmpInt
```

EDIT: not sure that my sample data and extra formatting made it clear how to adapt this to your query.  Maybe a side-by-side comparison would help?

Original:

```
select @tmpInt=coalesce(id,0) from MyView where id=9
```

Suggested:

```
SELECT @tmpInt = COALESCE(MAX(id),0) FROM MyView WHERE id = 9
```

Difference of five characters.

Comment: Edited to make things a bit clearer - not sure adding five characters is more of a 'hassle' than adding a re-initialization of a variable to multiple places in a script. My overly-OCD formatting and sample data might have made it confusing ...

Comment: But if `coalesce(id,0)` doesn't change the `@tmpInt` why will `coalesce(max(id),0)` do it? I have tested it and it does return `0` on non-existing rows but it makes no sense to me!?

Comment: It works because in SQL-Server, someone made the decision that [simple aggregate functions will return data even where there are no rows](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/11/13/sql-aggregate-totals.aspx): the same thing won't work in Oracle, but SQL is configured to allow it.  As to why they did so, I can't really speak to it; given [the number of questions asking Oracle to do the same thing](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+MAX+returns+zero+if+no+rows+found), maybe they had a good reason.

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer to this one as it answers my question. It's still unclear to me WHY this is working except this is a special feature allowed in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Because your select query returns no rows, no change is made to the @tmpInt.

If you made it so that it returned a row, but the value was null or 0, then the value of the variable would be changed.   But no row returned = no change to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, since you've initialised the `@tmpInt` to 5.

In case the select query would return `NULL` or any other value, it would have replaced the initial value of 5. But since you don't have any record `where id = 9`, then no row will be return.

Saying that, SQL will not set nothing value, it will rather return the value as is. Which explains the result 5, as initialised.