# sql prevent user from using SET

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-permissions

I have a database where I need to deny a user from using the set command. I have done tons of research with no positive results. I am familiar with setting roles or even using grant, revoke, or deny to a user.

My goal here is restrict my user from being able to set items like connection based variables or things like context_info.

Comment: If you somehow deny that permission, won't they still be able to [use SELECT to do the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/t-sql-set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot stop a user from using `SET`. I would COMPLETELY stay away from using anything such as context_info for the reasons you've already figured out, anything can happen to it.

I would also be wary of keeping session specific data or metadata anywhere in the database as it's going to be a security issue as well as a data accuracy issue.