# what is correct way to declare in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, select, declare

[image]

at line 79...

if query is "select @date = TglMasuk from MT_Pengemudi where id = '2' "
I succes view result... but just one result...

I hope i can view.. all result...in my query without "where id = '2' "
why without "where" failed like this picture ?

Btw, I created in sql server 2008 r2, variabel Tgl_masuk is date start work in my school, MT_Pengemudi is table name, tipe variabel TglMasuk is varchar.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/t-sql-set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables

Comment: `TglMasuk`'s datatype is `VARCHAR` and the conversion to date results in an out-of-range error.

Comment: You should mention the error in your question instead of "failed like this picture".

Comment: to Tim Schmelter : if at line 79 I addition condition where... my query succes... if not addition condition my query is failed.

to wewesthemenace : i try make set and make selecet... not difference...same is error...

thank's

Comment: in my case, how i can view result all... without condition like where ?

Comment: Why don't you cast to DATETIME while selecting?

Comment: to Kartic : if i casting its working ?
ok i try

Comment: to Kartic : i failed...