# SQL Server : Not So Simple IF Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to perform a simple `IF` statement. I have a table named 'products' that has a column `count` which is a current count of that specific product in stock. The `count` column in the database is of data type `INT`.

I can only get this to work if I statically assign the variable `@count`. If I assign a select statement to `@count` the script fails. Even though running the query alone will return a result.

Working query:

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 2

IF (@count > 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'It works!'
    END
```

Failing query:

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = (SELECT TOP 1 count from products WHERE count > 1)

IF (@count > 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'It works!'
    END
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 count from products WHERE count > 1` What is the result when you run this query

Comment: possible duplicate of [SET versus SELECT when assigning variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables)

Comment: "count" is column name in your products table, right?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 [count] from products WHERE [count] > 1`

Comment: You may also find this worth a read.http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194446/how-much-business-logic-should-the-database-implement

Comment: I'll try to answer your replies in one response. The result of the working query is '1'. Unfortunately 'count' is in fact the column name in the products table. I was not familiar of the differences between SET & SELECT when assigning variables (thank you lad2025). After reading the link I'm not sure that's the issue. Only because when I run my query outside of the if statement, it returns one result.

Comment: After changing to SELECT, I still have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = isnull((SELECT TOP 1 [count] from products WHERE [count] > 1),0)
IF (@count > 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'It works!'
    END
```

count is a [SQL Keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) that's why you need to use `[]` when you are using any `keywords` as a `column Name`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally use EXISTS

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * from products WHERE count > 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'It works!'
    END
```

Comment: Yes and this query is expected to act slightly different. My end result is that I need all rows where [count] > 1 to be inserted (duplicate rows) and have the total count dropped by one. I was simply attempting to break down my question to the lowest level :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having set= select simply use select to assign value to variable also `COUNT`is a key word in sql server use square brackets `[]` around it if you want sql server to treat it as an object name..... try this....

```
DECLARE @count INT
SELECT TOP 1 @count =  [count] from products WHERE count > 1

IF (@count > 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'It works!'
    END
```