# Handling NULL values while setting a value to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried the queries below to check whether the current year is Leap-Year or not.

```
Declare @leapyearstrt int = 0

--1st query
select @leapyearstrt = ISNULL(ISLEAPYEAR,0)
                       FROM [dbo].[TimeElement] 
                       WHERE CurrentDate = getdate()

--2nd query
SET @leapyearstrt  = (SELECT isnull(ISLEAPYEAR,0) 
                       FROM [dbo].[TimeElement] 
                       WHERE CurrentDate = getdate()
                       )
```

If the data does not exist in the table for the given date, 1st query returns `@leapyearstrt` as `0`, but 2nd query returns `@leapyearstrt` as `NULL`.

Why does it happen? How to assign the `0` value in the `SET` statement if data does not exist in the table?

(P.S : I have used `SET` to assign the value because `select` may return more than one row)

Comment: If there is no value then Parameter have to return the default value assign to it . is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SET versus SELECT when assigning variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if `SELECT` returns more than 1 row, then `SET` (your second query) fails:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

But, variable assignment within `SELECT` (your first query) works. It is not defined which row will be used to assign the final value, though.

---

If you want to use `SET`, then make sure that `SELECT` returns at most 1 row:

```
SET @leapyearstrt  = (SELECT TOP(1) isnull(ISLEAPYEAR,0) 
                       FROM [dbo].[TimeElement] 
                       WHERE CurrentDate = getdate()
        -- ideally you should add a proper ORDER BY to pick the row that you need
                       );
```

And then add this line of code to cover the case when `SELECT` returns 0 rows.

```
SET @leapyearstrt = ISNULL(@leapyearstrt, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNULL` function, assuming the subquery is returning one row:

```
SET @leapyearend  = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ISLEAPYEAR 
                            FROM [dbo].[TimeElement] 
                            WHERE CurrentDate = getdate()
                           ), 0)
```

The difference between those two is that in the first query if row is not found the assignment is not executed at all. In second version it is executed wether row is found or not.

Comment: What if subquery returns more than one row?

Comment: @lad2025, correct comment, added correction, but from names of table and columns I guess it shouldn't return more then one row.

Comment: OP says: `P.S : I have used SET to assign the value because select may return more than one row`

Comment: Is it safe to use Select instead of SET if query returning more than one row. I think SELECT will return top 1 row  if multiple rows are there