# Explain syntax: select @au_id = au_id from #mytemp (Equals sign in SELECT clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I come across similar queries that use `=` sign in the `select` statement every now but I always seem to skip over them because I don't really understand their logic. I would like a deeper explanation on the syntax. Also, I would like to know if you would use such a query only you have a variable involved? Is this a short form of

`SELECT * FROM #mytemp where @au_id = au_id`?

I guess my confusion stems from seeing an equals size in the `select` instead of `where` and I haven't come across any tutorials which show this syntax.

Here is the entire query example from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/111401). I understand what the query is doing but I would like to understand that one line better.

```
/********** example 1 **********/ 

declare @au_id char( 11 )

set rowcount 0
select * into #mytemp from authors

set rowcount 1

select @au_id = au_id from #mytemp

while @@rowcount <> 0
begin
    set rowcount 0
    select * from #mytemp where au_id = @au_id
    delete #mytemp where au_id = @au_id

    set rowcount 1
    select @au_id = au_id from #mytemp<BR/>
end
set rowcount 0
```

Comment: Nothing to do with `WHERE`,  in your example it assigns a value to a variable similar to `set @var = value`, see: [SET versus SELECT when assigning variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables)

Comment: Also using select top 1 instead of changing rowcount is usually a better way

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! That answers it for me. It would have been very helpful had I known how to search for help on this question :D