# Select statement MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my function **FirstDayInQtr**

This is the sql query

```
SELECT @day =  DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq ,0, @InputDate),0)
```

who can explain this statement

Comment: I'm sure we could all explain it. What exactly is your question though? Is it giving output that you wouldn't expect? Have you tested it with some sample data to see what it does?

Comment: yes i tested it and it works perfectly. but i cant understand logic behind this statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DATEADD()` function adds or subtracts a specified time interval from a date.

Syntax : **DATEADD(datepart,number,date)**

```
qq = quarter,

yy = Year
```

in your question the date field is representative as 0 or -1 in the datepart syntax, 
SQL server relates 0 as 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
and -1 as 1 day before 0 1899-12-31 00:00:00.000

so

```
select dateadd(qq,466,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') is the same as 


SELECT  DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq ,0, GETDATE()),0)

OR

SET @InsertDate = GETDATE()

SELECT   DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq ,0, @InsertDate),0)
```

Now, 466 is derived by the `datediff(qq,0,GETDATE())` section of the function. According to calender year there are 466 quaters between 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
and now.

so in `@day` u will get `2016-07-01 00:00:00.000`, if your `@InsertDate` value is `2016-07-05 00:00:00.000`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will clear your uncertainties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3945396/6492765

Basically, SELECT is a T-SQL way of setting a value for a variable, the magic being in selecting from joins or other select concepts directly into variables. With assigning 1 value to only 1 variable, it does not differ from SET which, in your case, would be:

```
SET @day = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq ,0, @InputDate),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign the first day of the current quarter to variable @day