# C# returns error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' but that should be ok

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to link two combo boxes in a C# winform app.

The first combobox - comboKategorija, once selected with the `_SelectedIndexChanged` sends the selected value from the combobox as an argument to a stored procedure.

```
private void comboKategorija_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataModel db = new DataModel();
    CheckInternet net = new CheckInternet();

    if (net.Available())
    {
        var validated = db.ChangeComboSifra(comboKategorija.Text);

        comboSifra.DataSource = validated;
        comboSifra.DisplayMember = "prefiks";
        comboSifra.ValueMember = "prefiks";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Интернет конекцијата е недостапна.", "Информација", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }    
}
```

I use dapper. The method is below. 
I pass only one argument - the selected value from the combox.

```
public List<Sifrarnik> ChangeComboSifra(string opis)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cloud"].ConnectionString))
    {
        if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            db.Open();
        }

        var response = db.Query<Sifrarnik>("dbo.spChangeComboSifra @opis",
            new
            {
                opis = opis
            }).ToList();
        return response;
    }
}
```

The stored procedure is support to return one or multiple rows, which will prepopulate the second combobox - comboboxSifra

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spChangeComboSifra]    
    @opis nvarchar(300)    
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @MyPrefiks nvarchar(100)    
    SET @MyPrefiks = (SELECT prefiks from Sifrarnik where opis LIKE '%' + @opis + '%')
    SELECT prefiks,opis FROM Sifrarnik where SUBSTRING(prefiks, 1,2) = @MyPrefiks  and LEN(prefiks) > 2
END
```

However I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

It says more than one value returned, which is exactly what I want. But I'm not sure why the error?

Comment: The error is being causes by this line in your SP `SET @MyPrefiks = (SELECT prefiks from Sifrarnik where opis LIKE '%' + @opis + '%')` - you can't assign more than 1 value to a variable.

Comment: "return one or multiple rows" so you need to return that set of one or more rows and put that into a list perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one Sifrarnik that has an opis matching whatever you're passing in the @opis variable:

```
SET @MyPrefiks = (SELECT prefiks from Sifrarnik where opis LIKE '%' + @opis + '%')
```

If this query matches 2+ rows, the execution of the SP will halt with an error. Decide how you want to ensure that this query returns only a single row. You could:

```
SET @MyPrefiks = (SELECT MAX(prefiks) from Sifrarnik where opis LIKE '%' + @opis + '%')

SET @MyPrefiks = (SELECT TOP 1 prefiks from Sifrarnik where opis LIKE '%' + @opis + '%' ORDER BY ...)
```

And so on

If the query returns multiple rows but you genuinely want to use all of them you'll have to use its output to drive the query that @MyPrefiks formerly used, for example:

```
SELECT prefiks,opis 
FROM Sifrarnik 
where 
  SUBSTRING(prefiks, 1,2) IN (SELECT prefiks from Sifrarnik where opis LIKE '%' + @opis + '%') 
  and LEN(prefiks) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `SET` only works if you return zero or one rows. `SELECT`, on the other hand, works fine regardless of the number of the rows returned (although only *one* of the values will be assigned). As such, you could use:

```
SELECT @MyPrefiks = prefiks from Sifrarnik where opis LIKE '%' + @opis + '%'
```

*Note that `SET` and `SELECT` will act [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3945396/34092) if the query returns no rows (`SET` will set it the variable to `NULL` while `SELECT` will leave it unchanged).*