# When does SELECT not make a table as an output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, variable-assignment

I am a novice in SQL and I am following a web tutorial. I encountered a piece of code where  SELECT statement assigns a value to a variable. I suspect that such SELECT statements don't make a table as a result. E.g. when I want to mix the assignment with a column name as in:

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT 
    @columns += QUOTENAME(category_name) + ',',
    category_name
FROM 
    production.categories
ORDER BY 
    category_name;

SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

PRINT @columns;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

(Following this [course](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/) on Internet with [database](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/SQL-Server-Sample-Database.zip))

My question is if there exists another form of data manipulation (as an assignment) that in a SELECT statement don't produce a table (if my assumption is right).

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. You're trying to assign the value of `@columns` **and** return the value of `category_name`. The error, I'm afraid, can't be more clear. A `SELECT` can only do one, or the other, but not both.

Comment: I don't understand your question: _if there exists another form of data manipulation (as an assignment) that in a SELECT statement don't produce a table (if my assumption is right)._. If you took `category_name` out of that statement, it would be a SELECT doing an assignment and not producing a result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I my question is:
"Does there exist another form of data manipulation (as an assignment) that in a SELECT statement don't produce a table (if my assumption is right)."

Comment: If you want to assign all values into variable , the following part of code will  be help you;   @columns = STRING_AGG(category_name,';')  WITHIN  GROUP (ORDER BY category_name)

Comment: That is not a good "tutorial" - rather, it appears to be a bunch of topics grouped into sections that do not actually guide you or build the skills in a method to encourage success. Find another. A pivot is something you should leave until you master basic sql. What you are trying to do is a dynamic pivot which is even more  complex. And this usage uses a "trick" to aggregate strings that is discouraged.

Comment: Whoever voted this down: Please keep in mind, that this is a new contributor and states clearly to be a novice with the topic. Here's someone trying to learn something. No reason to put one down... The question is clear and not stupid in any way. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you do, `SELECT` will always return a TABLE.

Creating a stored procedure with a lots of criteria is giving you the option to either return a TABLE or returns a VARIABLE.

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE_INPUT VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @VARIABLE_OUTPUT VARCHAR(50);

SET @VARIABLE_INPUT = 'THIS_IS_INPUT';
EXEC storedProcedureTEST @VARIABLE_INPUT, @VARIABLE_OUTPUT OUTPUT;

PRINT 'The Output of storedProcedureTEST is: ' + @VARIABLE_OUTPUT ;
```

In your `storedProcedureTEST`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE storedProcedureTEST
    @VARIABLE_INPUT VARCHAR(50),
    @VARIABLE_OUTPUT VARCHAR(50)='' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @VARIABLE_OUTPUT = @VARIABLE_INPUT + '_ABC';
END
```

Result:

The output of `storedProcedureTEST` is: THIS_IS_INPUT_ABC

Comment: It might be a matter of taste, but it is - in my eyes - a very bad advise to use a stored procedure for this. Best was an *inline TVF*, which you can `APPLY` to your query. This SP forces you into *procedural thinking*, away from the much better *set-based thinking*...

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question actually... The OP wants to create a concatenated list of all `category_name` values found in a table... I hope you would not suggest to use a `CURSOR` together with this SP...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question literally:

> When does SELECT not make a table as an output

Never!

The `SELECT` returns a result set, consisting of rows, and each row consisting of columns.

There is a special situation, when your result set comes back with *exactly one row* with *one single column*. This can be taken as a **scalar value** and therefore be assigned to a variable.

You can enforce a single row with a `TOP 1` or with a `WHERE`-clause that guarantees to return never more than one row. But the engine will not see this in advance. Your provided code mentions two columns, the one with the `QUOTENAME()` and - after the comma - once more the `category_name`. That's why you get the exception.

It is a similar situation, when you want to test a list, e.g. with

```
WHERE SomeID IN(SELECT TheId FROM AnotherTable)
```

The SELECT within the `IN()` will return a list of ID values, but there will be just one column.

### UPDATE Some hints upon your code...

What you are doing here:

```
SELECT 
    @columns += QUOTENAME(category_name) + ',',
    category_name
FROM
```

... is called *quirky update* and might work without the second mention of `category_name`. It is roughly an *iteration* through the table's values where each row *adds* to the previously set value of `@column`.

This approach is very dangerous and should be avoided (or used with some [backgorund knowledge](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten)).

Starting with v2017 there is `STRING_AGG()` and before I'd prefer the approach with `FOR XML PATH('')`

### Example

Try this:

```
USE master;
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)='';
```

--Your approach with the quirky update

```
SELECT 
    @columns += QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ',' 
FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='spt_fallback_db';

SELECT @columns;
```

--The recommended approach with XML

```
SET @columns=
STUFF(
(SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
 FROM 
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='spt_fallback_db'
 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');

 SELECT @columns;
```

--and - v2017+ needed - with STRING_AGG()

```
SELECT @columns=STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),',')
FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='spt_fallback_db';

SELECT @columns;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Shnugo. It gave me something to chew about the way how the SELECT functions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert from row to single line column right

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

set @columns = (select concat(quotename ,' : ', category_name) from production.categories order by category_name for xml path(''))


PRINT @columns;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a quick solution from the box.